# From a binary search tree, how would I find what path weighs the most using recursion? Using Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

[image: Tree]

If I had a binary search tree like the one in the image what would a traversal method look like, that could recursively find the path that weighs the most?

I tried doing an inOrder traversal but don't think I was writing it correctly. So an example that could work for this would be much appreciated.

edit:

```
private static void inOrder(BinaryNode tree) {
if(tree == null) return;

if (tree is an end node) {
 update the end node array
}

if(tree.rightchild != null) {
       parent[rightChild.getLabel()] = tree;
}
if(tree.leftChild != null) {
       parent[leftChild.getLabel()] = tree;
}

inOrder(tree.leftChild);
inOrder(tree.rightChild);
}
```

Class that supports the one I'm trying to write

```
// Basic BinaryNode class, Feel free to edit this case.

public class BinaryNode {
    private String label; // The label of the node
    private BinaryNode[] childs; // childs[0] points to the left child, and childs[1] points to the right child
    private int[] weights; // weights[0] is the funness of the left ski path from here, and weights[1]
    // is the funness of the right ski path from here.
    private boolean edge;

    // Feel free to add extra data fields and methods to cater to your implementation.
    // However, please do not edit anything that is already provided, as these are needed
    // to build the tree from the input.

    // Constructor
    public BinaryNode(String label, BinaryNode left, BinaryNode right, int lw, int rw) {
        this.label = label;
        this.childs = new BinaryNode[]{left, right};
        this.weights = new int[]{lw, rw};
    }

    // Accessors and Mutators
    public BinaryNode getLeftChild() {
        return childs[0];
    }

    public void setLeftChild(BinaryNode child) {
        this.childs[0] = child;
    }

    public BinaryNode getRightChild() {
        return childs[1];
    }

    public void setRightChild(BinaryNode child) {
        this.childs[1] = child;
    }

    public int getLeftWeight() {
        return weights[0];
    }

    public void setLeftWeight(int child) {
        this.weights[0] = child;
    }

    public int getRightWeight() {
        return weights[1];
    }

    public void setRightWeight(int child) {
        this.weights[1] = child;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Node: " + this.label;
    }
}
```

```
// Don't Edit this class
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryTree {
    private BinaryNode root;
    private HashMap<String, BinaryNode> nodes;
    private ArrayList<String[]> fileLinesToProcess;
    
    public BinaryTree(){
        this.nodes = new HashMap<>(); 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.fileLinesToProcess = customRead(kb);
        if(this.fileLinesToProcess.size() != 0){
            int i = 0;
            String[] shouldBeRoot = this.fileLinesToProcess.get(0);
            this.root = new BinaryNode(shouldBeRoot[0], null, null, 0, 0);
            this.nodes.put(shouldBeRoot[0], this.root);
            while(this.fileLinesToProcess.size() != i){
                String[] line = this.fileLinesToProcess.get(i);
                BinaryNode tnode = this.nodes.getOrDefault(line[0], null);
                BinaryNode othernode = this.nodes.getOrDefault(line[1], null);

                if(tnode == null){
                    tnode = new BinaryNode(line[0], null, null, 0, 0);
                }

                if(othernode == null){
                    othernode = new BinaryNode(line[1], null, null, 0, 0);
                }

                this.nodes.put(line[0], tnode);
                this.nodes.put(line[1], othernode);

                if(tnode.getLeftChild() == null){
                    tnode.setLeftChild(othernode);
                    tnode.setLeftWeight(Integer.parseInt(line[2]));
                }else{
                    tnode.setRightChild(othernode);
                    tnode.setRightWeight(Integer.parseInt(line[2]));
                }

                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String[]> customRead(Scanner fileInp){
        ArrayList<String[]> output = new ArrayList<>();
        while(fileInp.hasNext()){
            String[] nums = fileInp.nextLine().split(" ");
            output.add(nums);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public BinaryNode getRoot(){
        return this.root;
    }

    public static void turnBSTtoString(BinaryNode root){
        if(root == null) return;

        if(root.getLeftChild() != null){
            System.out.println(root.getLabel() + " " + root.getLeftChild().getLabel() + " " + root.getLeftWeight());
        }
        if(root.getRightChild() != null){
            System.out.println(root.getLabel() + " " + root.getRightChild().getLabel() + " " + root.getRightWeight());
        }

        turnBSTtoString(root.getLeftChild());
        turnBSTtoString(root.getRightChild());

        return;
    }
}
```

[sample input:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChbR1.png)
sample output:
[output for the tree image shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyja0.png)

Comment: Please add the method you wrote so we can help you

Comment: Asoub, I added the psuedo code I was trying to write

Comment: Mhh, that's still a little opaque, you would need to explain a little more. What's a BinaryNode ? what do you mean by "update the end array" ? is the dinal weight the sum of node and branch weight ? You're not so far from the "traversal" part, use print to debug where you are, and try passing current weight to the next 'inOrder' call.

Comment: Ok, I added the BinaryNode class, hopefully that helps clear it uo

Comment: There is no binary search tree here. What is the desired data structure for the output? Your `inorder` function a `void` one...

Comment: My point is: this is not a binary search tree.

Comment: Well it is a Binary Tree. The desired data structure is one that could answer  "What happens when you call recursion on the left tree or the right tree. You should get the best path from the left child to a leaf, and the right child to a leaf respectively. So, consider only what you need to do at the root (of the subtree in recursion) to compute the best path from it."

Comment: Yes, it is. So what is your point when calling it a binary search tree? You need to convert it to one?

Comment: Did not mean to call it a search tree

Comment: trincot can you help please? I added to the comment for clarification.

Comment: What is the desired data structure for the output? Your inorder function is a void one... Please provide the code that constructs a tree, and calls the function and prints the result, and indicate where things go wrong.

Comment: I don't know what the desired data structure is. I added the code that constructs the tree to the original post.  The desired data structure is one that could answer "What happens when you call recursion on the left tree or the right tree. You should get the best path from the left child to a leaf, and the right child to a leaf respectively. So, consider only what you need to do at the root (of the subtree in recursion) to compute the best path from it."

Comment: OK, then that's the end of the question for me, because you will not be able to tell if a solution would be correct or not.

Comment: The desired data structure is supposed to be an Inorder traversal

Comment: An inorder traversal is an algorithm. But what is the expected outcome? For instance, an output could be "go left, left, left, left, left". Or it could be the "maximised sum is 16", or it could be "visit 1 2 4 8 17", or it could be just "17", or an ArrayList of TreeNode objects, or ....etc, etc. You'll have to tell us.

Comment: Ok I added a picture of the sample output for tree image shown in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a recursive function, like that *inorder* function, but the `inorder` code you presented is wrong in many respects as it doesn't even use existing properties of the `BinaryNode` class.

That recursive function should return the maximum weight *and* corresponding path it finds in the tree rooted at the given node. The base case occurs when the given node is null. In that case that maximum weight is 0, and the path is empty.

There are several ways you can think of organising the return value. I went for an `ArrayList<Integer>` whose first entry is the maximum weight, and all other entries are either 0 or 1 to represent a walk to the left or to the right.

Here is that function:

```
    private static ArrayList<Integer> heaviestPath(BinaryNode root) {
        if (root == null) return new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(0); }};
        ArrayList<Integer> leftPath = heaviestPath(root.getLeftChild());
        ArrayList<Integer> rightPath = heaviestPath(root.getRightChild());
        if (leftPath.get(0) < rightPath.get(0)) {
            rightPath.set(0, rightPath.get(0) + root.getRightWeight());
            rightPath.add(1);
            return rightPath;
        } else {
            leftPath.set(0, leftPath.get(0) + root.getLeftWeight());
            leftPath.add(0);
            return leftPath;
        }
    }
```

Here is how you could call it when you have a reference to a `root` node:

```
        BinaryNode root;
        // Construct the tree
        // ... your code ...
        //
     
        // Get the heaviest path starting from the root
        ArrayList<Integer> path = heaviestPath(root);
        // Extract the weight of the path and output it
        int weight = path.get(0);
        path.remove(0);
        System.out.println("Largest funness: " + weight);
        // Use the rest of the arraylist to walk along the path and print its node labels
        BinaryNode node = root;
        for (int side : path) {
            System.out.println("Node: " + node.getLabel());
            if (side == 1) {
                node = node.getRightChild();
            } else {
                node = node.getLeftChild();
            }
        }
```